# expected value using generating function

Tags: probability

What is expected value of $X$. Generating function of $X$ is $g_X(t) = e^{t-1}$.

$$EX=g_X'(1) = e^{1-1} = 1$$

Tell me please, Is it ok ?

Comment: Yes, it’s fine.

Answer (score 0):

"Generating function" in this context is not sufficiently precise.  The probability distribution of a random variable $X$ has a **moment** generating function (if it exists) $$M_X(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{tX}],$$ and/or a **probability** generating function (if it exists) $$P_X(t) = \operatorname{E}[t^X].$$  You have not specified which type of generating function is described by $g_X(t)$.

If $g$ describes the former, then $$\operatorname{E}[X]= \left[ \frac{dM_X(t)}{dt} \right]_{t=0}.$$  If it describes the latter, then $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \left[\frac{dP_X(t)}{dt}\right]_{t=1},$$ where in either case we may take the limit as $t \to 0$ or $t \to 1$ if the derivative is not strictly defined at those points.